# Configuration of Blazor wasm in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, blazor-webassembly

I make an app with blazor wasm in VSCode.
When I build my app I add the error below :

error CS0246: Le nom de type ou d'espace de noms 'MainLayout' est introuvable (vous manque-t-il une directive using ou une référence d'assembly ?) [...source\repos\WebApp3\Client\WebApp3.Client.csproj]

In program.cs the App.razor is not recognized :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qoU8R.png)

The problem is probably due to the settings in the .csproj file.
Have you an idea ?

Comment: Your first part of question is not clear. As to that error you see in Program.cs for <App>, there is an open issue at https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/33858
Meanwhile as a workaround, downgrade the C# extension from 1.23.12 to 1.23.11, as pointed here https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-vscode/issues/4618#issuecomment-869689003 It worked for me.

Comment: Hi, thanks to your reply. you're right I see the in program.cs for <App>. I will check your link

Comment: Thanks a lot. All things is OK with the version 1.23.11.